# Now column from row that meets criteria in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I am fairly new to R, and I am struggling to make much progress with my problem. A simplified version of my R data frame is as follows:

```
id year num_inst 
1  1995 4  
1  1996 3
1  1996 3
2  1995 1
2  1997 2 
2  1998 2
3  2005 4
4  1998 1
4  1999 7
...
```

What I am trying to do is add a new column value to each row labelled num_inst_prior which is dependent on a given row that meets a certain criteria. What I am after is the following:

```
id year num_inst num_inst_prior 
1  1995 4        NA
1  1996 3        4
1  1996 3        4
2  1995 1        NA
2  1997 2        NA
2  1998 2        2
3  2005 4        NA
4  1998 1        NA
4  1999 7        1
...
```

That is I want a column to represent the number of instances (num_inst) for a given id for the previous year i.e., when year = 1996 and id = 1, what is the number of instances in the prior year (num_inst_prior = 4; 1995).

I have attempted to add a new column

```
> df$prior_year <- df$year - 1
```

And considered using the which function as a first step, but it seems to only operate row wise. Such that I am stuck at the first hurdle with no 'whiches'.

```
> which(df$year == df$prior_year & df$id == df$id)
integer(0)
```

Any assistance that points me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can look at `lag` after grouping by 'id'

Comment: I don't think it is as simple as that, as not all year data is provided for a given id. I.e., I need it to show NA, if no num_inst values appear in the previous year for a certain id.

Answer (score 1):

You should go for `mutate` and `lag` from the `dplyr` package.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(id = 1:5,
           year = 1991:1995, 
           prior = 5:9)

  id year prior
1  1 1991     5
2  2 1992     6
3  3 1993     7
4  4 1994     8
5  5 1995     9

df %>% 
  mutate(prior_n1 = lag(prior, 1))

  id year prior prior_n1
1  1 1991     5       NA
2  2 1992     6        5
3  3 1993     7        6
4  4 1994     8        7
5  5 1995     9        8
```

Here, prior_n1 is the name of the column to ouptut in, and lag the function taking : the name of the original column, and the length of the lag.

Best,

Colin

Comment: Thanks Colin, however, this doesn't seem to do the job with duplicate ids and/or  years for a given id as in my example (duplicates are necessary as more information is carried in other columns). It is perhaps not as simple as lag, as the information is not necessarily obtained from the previous row.